# Action happens when paypal payment is paid

Tags: php, paypal

i'm a newbie to web dev and what I need to do is create a form where a user inputs something into a field lets just call it name for now.....then when they go to paypal they donate $1 (predetermined) then from when paid to paypal, they are redirected to a success page and what I want that success page to do is say "confirmed" and the action for it to do is grab the "name" that was given and input it into a txt file on the server

Is there a way I can do this securely...i've never had to do anything with paypal before that wasn't a premade script.

(would be using php)

(if there is a script in wordpress/joomla (haven't decided which i'll use yet i'd probably use it)

As long as I can somehow get that variable "name" and do what I want with it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the paypal IPN and there are a number of implementations and tutorials on it, try googling for it...

Comment: And the 'item_name' PayPal HTML parameter to pass along the item name visibly, or 'custom' if it needs to be hidden. (`<input type="text" name="custom" value"Your name here">`)